# How do I use angular directives as comments?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` as [comment directives](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/docs/guide/directive) but **[neither seems to work (plnkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/pUX3C0sgC0f6uq3JFlv9?p=preview)**.

```
<div><strong>Loop this:</strong></div>

<!-- directive: ng-repeat-start: val in arr -->
  <p ng-if="true">Hello {{val}}!</p>
<!-- directive: ng-repeat-end -->

<strong>Don't show this stuff:</strong>

<!-- directive: ng-if false -->
  <div ng-repeat-start="val in arr">{{val}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat-end>({{val*2}})</div>
<!-- end directive: ng-if -->
```

(note that `$scope.arr = [1,2,3,4,5];`)

*What gives?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because both of them are declared to be used as attributes only:
[ng-repeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/docs/guide/directive), [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).
Check the 'Usage' section